# Create a new table in SQuirreL SQL through the GUI?

Tags: mysql, sql, squirrel-sql

Is it possible to create a new table in SQuirreL SQL through the GUI?

I can't seem to find a way to do it on the UI. This is one of the most basic piece of functionality that a db visual tool should have so I would be very surprised if you cannot do this and have to create tables via scripts.

Any help would be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, SQuirreL SQL does not have this functionality (as of version 3.6).

SQuirreL SQL is not a "db visual tool", but a "universal SQL client" (as self-advertised) that...

> (...) will allow you to view the structure of a JDBC compliant
>   database, browse the data in tables, issue SQL commands etc.<sup>[1](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/#overview)</sup>

It just so happens that it comes with a graphical user interface.